# Discord.py Image Posting

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that posts a random image (for this example lets say `bread`) from google images. Right now I'm stuck with trying to post the image to Discord.
Here is the code:

```
import discord
import io
import aiohttp
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('/bread'):
        #await message.channel.send('bread!')
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=bread&tbm=isch") as resp:
                if resp.status != 200:
                    return await message.channel.send('Could not download file...')
                data = io.BytesIO(await resp.read())
                await message.channel.send(file=discord.File(data, 'image.png'))

client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

Whenever I run the `/bread` command, I run into the `could not download file` error.
I don't want to download the image, I just want it posted to discord. I tried selecting a specific image URL, it too did not work.

Answer (score 0):

About picture:
You can go at igmur.com and create own link to picture. You just have to drag picture to the site.(this pictures works at discord)

And that's my script for posting URL by bot

```
import random
Import discord
import http.client
from discord.ext import commands
Import aiohttp

@bot.command()
async def /bread(ctx):
    messages = ["url", "bread2url", "bread3url"]
    await ctx.send(random.choice(messages))
```